# Bond Benchmarks Not relying on Bloomberg

Tags: fixed-income

I have previously hit this forum for some guidance on getting benchmark curve members (link below). I have managed to get this working with Bloomberg, but I was wondering, is there any way to reliably get this info across the curve *without relying on Bloomberg*?

I have thought to scrape this information directly from the Treasury (for ex) but are there any other resources online for this?

Cheers!

[Bloomberg: Get Historical Benchmarks](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/69144/bloomberg-get-historical-benchmarks)

Comment: How did you resolve the previous question?

Comment: There is an excel template on the terminal (XLTP <GO>) that has a relevant BDS command. An override lets you specify the date.

Comment: thanks for sharing this information.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a rough outline of what you can do:

1. You can retrieve all the historical Treasury auctions via [this url](http://www.treasurydirect.gov/TA_WS/securities/jqsearch?format=json&securityTypeoperator=and&filtervalue0=Note&filtercondition0=EQUAL&filteroperator0=1&filterdatafield0=securityType&filtervalue1=Bond&filtercondition1=EQUAL&filteroperator1=1&filterdatafield1=securityType&filterscount=2&groupscount=0&sortdatafield=auctionDate&sortorder=desc&pagenum=0&pagesize=2000&recordstartindex=0&recordendindex=100).
2. To make things easier, I recommend that you compute a `rounded_term` for each auctioned issue, which can be calculated as $(\text{maturityDate} -  \text{issueDate}) / 365$, rounded to the nearest integer. This is simply the original term to maturity in years.
3. Then on each trading day, you simply query for all issues for the `rounded_term` of interest, sort them by `auctionDate`, and use the most recently auctioned issue.

Comment: Helpful, thanks!